# Полсе замены принимаемого значения DataSource в Repository приложение начало вылетать

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, di

Я использую архитектуру MVVM. Поменял в классе `DescriptionRepository` строку `private val dataSource: RDDataSource` на `private val dataSource: DescriptionDataSource`:

```
class DescriptionRepository(private val dataSource: DescriptionDataSource) : DescriptionCall {

    override fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {
        return dataSource.loadDescription()
    }

}
```

стала вылетать ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sem.receivedata, PID: 17467
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/sem/receivedata/data/dataSource/RDDataSource;)V in class Lcom/sem/receivedata/data/repository/DescriptionRepository; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.sem.receivedata.data.repository.DescriptionRepository' appears in /data/data/com.sem.receivedata/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes10.dex)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$4.invoke(AppModules.kt:74)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$4.invoke(AppModules.kt:74)
```

Судя по 3 строке ошибки, скорее всего, я что-то где-то забыл поменять, но сколько ни просматривал код, так и не нашёл (это моё предположение, может быть дело в чём нибудь другом).

`di`:

```
val description = module {

    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            androidContext(), ReceiveDataDB::class.java,
            "dbO"
        ).build()
    }

    single { get<ReceiveDataDB>().nameListDao }

    single<DescriptionDataSource> {
        DescriptionDataSourceIMPL(
            get()
        )
    }

    single<DescriptionCall> { DescriptionRepository(get()) }


    single { DescriptionUseCase(get()) }


    viewModel { DescriptionViewModel(get()) }

}
```

Цепочка классов и интерфейсов:

`DescriptionDataSource`:

```
interface DescriptionDataSource {

    fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>>

}
```

`DescriptionDataSourceIMPL`

```
    class DescriptionDataSourceIMPL(private val dao: DescriptionDao): DescriptionDataSource {
        override fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {
            return dao.loadDescription()
        }

}
```

`DescriptionDao`:

```
@Dao
interface DescriptionDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pagination_table")
    fun loadDescription() : LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>>

}
```

`DescriptionRepository`:

```
class DescriptionRepository(private val dataSource: DescriptionDataSource) : DescriptionCall {

    override fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {
        return dataSource.loadDescription()
    }

}
```

`DescriptionCall`:

```
interface DescriptionCall {

    fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>>

}
```

`DescriptionUseCase`:

```
class DescriptionUseCase(private val descriptionCall: DescriptionCall) {

    fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {

        return descriptionCall.loadDescription()

    }

}
```

`DescriptionViewModel`:

```
class DescriptionViewModel(private val descriptionUseCase: DescriptionUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    val loadDescription = descriptionUseCase.loadDescription()

}
```

`stacktrace`:

```
2022-09-09 15:14:02.207 32418-32418/com.sem.receivedata E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sem.receivedata, PID: 32418
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/sem/receivedata/data/dataSource/RDDataSource;)V in class Lcom/sem/receivedata/data/repository/DescriptionRepository; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.sem.receivedata.data.repository.DescriptionRepository' appears in /data/data/com.sem.receivedata/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes10.dex)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$4.invoke(AppModules.kt:74)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$4.invoke(AppModules.kt:74)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:54)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:46)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
        at org.koin.mp.KoinPlatformTools.synchronized(KoinPlatformTools.kt:20)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:111)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:255)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:242)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:205)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$5.invoke(AppModules.kt:87)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$5.invoke(AppModules.kt:77)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:54)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:46)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:53)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
        at org.koin.mp.KoinPlatformTools.synchronized(KoinPlatformTools.kt:20)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:111)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:255)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:242)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:205)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$6.invoke(AppModules.kt:87)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.di.AppModulesKt$description$1$6.invoke(AppModules.kt:80)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:54)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:111)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:255)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:242)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:205)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.factory.DefaultViewModelFactory.create(DefaultViewModelFactory.kt:13)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:83)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.DescriptionFragment.getDescriptionViewModel(DescriptionFragment.kt:20)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.DescriptionFragment.onCreateView(DescriptionFragment.kt:31)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
2022-09-09 15:14:02.207 32418-32418/com.sem.receivedata E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.bind$lambda-0(NameListAdapter.kt:69)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.$r8$lambda$FuXGFWDKhm2ZD3YhtF7Xh98aUvc(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7462)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7426)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:811)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28323)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Если щёлкнуть по `AppModules.kt:87` выпадает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Inline function body` перекидывает в метод `inline fun <reified T : Any>` get класса `data class Scope` (туда, где `return`):

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> get(
    qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
): T {
    return get(T::class, qualifier, parameters)
}
```

Comment: Приведите полный stacktrace. Судя по тому что ошибка в рантайме, ищите что в DI забыли поменять. Простую ошибку в коде отловил бы компилятор.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, добавил в текст вопроса

Comment: Пройдите AppModules.kt:80 -> 87 -> 77 -> 74, где-то там встретите конструктор с параметром типа RDDataSource.

Comment: `AppModules.kt` указывают на следующие строки в `di`: 74 на строку `single<DescriptionCall> { DescriptionRepository(get()) }`, 77 на `single { DescriptionUseCase(get()) }`, 80 и 87 на `viewModel { DescriptionViewModel(get()) }`,

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, если щёлкнуть на 87, он предлагает на выбор `Inline function body` (перекидывает в метод `inline fun <reified T : Any> get` класса `data class Scope`) и `Inline function call site` (указывает на  `viewModel { DescriptionViewModel(get()) }`)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, код недостающих классов и интерфейса в вопрос добавил